# Compare tables and select match rows to single row of other table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables and both of them contains multiple matching records, I want to identify only the matching contacts between the two tables and to be compared with single row and skip if not matching.

```
table A                                                   table B
name |amount                                      name|amount
A    |20                                            C | 50
B    |20                                            A | 20
C    |50                                            A | 20
A    |20                                            B | 50
B    |20                                            B | 20
c    |20                                            C | 20
                                                    C | 50
```

so I want to write a SQL query to get a  result like B 50 and C 50 is not matching so I can highlight them

```
 table A                                                   table B
    name |amount                                      name|amount
    A    |20                                            A | 20
    A    |20                                            A | 20
    B    |20                                            A | 20
    B    |20                                            B | 20
    C    |20                                            B | 20
    C    |20                                            C | 20
                                                        C | 20
                                                        C | 20
                                                        C | 20
```

so I want a result like this which is returned from table B as these entries are not matching.

```
A 20 
C 20
C 20
```

Comment: What is the query you have tried to write..?

Comment: @KaushikNayak i am not getting the idea only so not able to figure it out

Comment: both table have c with amount 20 and 50. Which one do you want to see? Give more example.

Comment: @KemalGüler yes but c50 has appeared twice in table B and only once in table A so table B has extra one so i want to display the extra one

Comment: Could you try to explain again what you want to obtain ? Or give the result you expect in your example ? It's difficult to understand what you want here.

Comment: @Eria the table A contains only 1 entry for c50 but the table B contains 2 so iwant to display the extra one

Comment: You should edit post. I don't understand what you want @AkshayWani

Comment: @KemalGüler updated ..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that ?

```
select a2.name, a2.amount
from ( select name, amount, count(*) as n from A group by name, amount ) a2
join ( select name, amount, count(*) as n from B group by name, amount ) b2 on b2.name = a2.name and b2.amount = a2.amount
where b2.n <> a2.n
```

Since I don't know what result you want when a couple name/amount exists in A and not in B (or in B and not in A), you may have to adapt it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT c.name, c.amount, o.name, o.amount
FROM tableA AS c, TableB AS o
WHERE c.name=o.amount AND c.amount=o.amount;`

This is an idea of the way, you should try, bot not complete answer.

Also you should try to combine with this: 
`SELECT c.name, c.amount, o.name, o.amount, Count(*) as Duplicates
FROM tableA AS c, TableB AS o
WHERE c.name=o.amount AND c.amount=o.amount
having Duplicates > 1;`